# Scatter Plot and missing values

Tags: python, matplotlib, missing-data

I'm very new to python and I'm experimenting with matplotlib.pyplot.
I'm plotting my data using a scatter plot. What I could see from the descriptive statistics all of my columns have 1/4 of missing values.
So my question is how does a scatter plot treats missing values?
does it ignore them (excluding them from the plot)
or
it replaces the values by 0?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are `nan` they are not plotted.

Example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,np.nan,np.nan, 3, 4]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

On the contrary with `y = [1,0,0,3,4]`:
[image]

Of course you can replace the `nan` with `0` or other values. The 'how' depends the kind of your data. For list:

```
import math
y = [0 if math.isnan(e) else e for e in y]
```